# GetFeature WFS call to see if a particular feature exists - deliver WMS content based on the response

Tags: geoserver, getfeature

If I want to send a WFS query to my GeoServer server (A) from another server (B) - not any browser - what interface would I usually use? I am only familiar with accessing the GeoServer server from a browser via JavaScript and OpenLayers.

---

I run PHP on Server B. Browser communicates directly with server B. Server B delivers OpenLayers JavaScript to the browser. Usually, OpenLayers JavaScript communicates from the browser directly with my GeoServer server (A). Now, I want server A to send a query to server B, that obtains some data directly which would have been otherwise gone the longer way through the browser and OpenLayers.

I can do it like this:

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://mygeoserver?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&typeName=mytType:myName");
doSomeXMLSParseOperations($content);
```

but I am not sure if that is the regular solution.

Comment: You need to specify what servers you are using and what sort of Query what you want to actually do? Are you talking about cascaded WMS, Admin Interface??

Comment: I don't know yet what is cascaded WMS and Admin Interface but I explained a little more what I want.

Comment: What do you want to do with the data on Server A. deliver it to a Browser Client? You need to be very specific about exactly what you want to achieve .. Are you trying to create a Proxy to deliver Wms requests from bots Servers?

Comment: I want to check whether a certain data record exists at all. What I deliver to the browser client will depend on whether this data record exists or not.

Comment: Are you trying to do a GetFeature WFS call to see if a particular feature exists and then deliver WMS content based on the response?

Comment: yes, exactly this.

Comment: Cool .. Please modify your question to reflect this  requirement ... It will help you get the answers you need and help others in the future who may view this question ..